# Transfer data from text area in an html file to another php file

Tags: php, html

My problem is that I want to make a blog. I am really new to coding so I'm not very good. My main issue is sending code from the text area in the html file to the PHP file which I don't even know how to fix.

[this is a image of the file where someone types their blog it is a html file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NECxz.png)

[this is the image of the storage place or where all the blogs will be put. It is a phpfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqVvw.png)

Code for blog.html file (where you write the stuff)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <body>
  <h2 style="background-color:blue;color:white">
  TheBlog
  </h2>
 </head></font>
   <p> <center><h5 style="background-color:blue;color:white">
   This is where you can type the text!</p>
   </h5></center> 
    <form action="Storage-Area-For-Blog.php" method="post"> 
   <textarea name="txtcomment" cols="160" rows="40"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Publish">  
    <input type="reset" name="Clear">
    </form>
 <h5><ul>
   <li><a href="Blog-Homepage.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="Blog-Creating-Process.html">Creation Process</a></li>
  </ul></h5>
  </body>-->
</html>
```

code for storage area

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <body>
  <?php echo $_POST['txtcomment']; ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is HTML Forms 101. You may want to take some tutorials befor you get much further.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code _directly_ into the question. Screenshots aren't searchable, can't be copied, and offer poor accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

file form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <h2 style="background-color:blue;color:white">
        TheBlog
        </h2>

    <h5 style="background-color:blue;color:white; text-align: center">
                This is where you can type the text!</h5>

    <form name="test" action="process_form.php" method="post">
        <textarea name="txtcomment" id="txtcomment" cols="160" rows="40"></textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Publish">
        <input type="reset" name="clear">
    </form>
    <h5><ul>
            <li><a href="blog-homepage.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog-breating-process.html">Creation Process</a></li>
        </ul></h5>
</body>
</html>
```

file process_form.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php echo $_POST['txtcomment']; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

this works...

Comment: thank you. However, the text from the html file will still not appear into that php file. Do you know any ways around it?

Comment: you missed the opening <html> tag

Comment: there where a lot of errors in your code, p and h5 overlapping tags, deprecated tags, closed head inside the body tag.